# GPU won´t render properly

Tags: rendering, gpu

when i use my GPU to render an Animation it only uses about 5% of it. I enabled CUDA in the Preferences and selected my GPU but it is still not working. 
I have a GTX 1080 Graphics card.
Any answers ?

Comment: Have you enabled GPU rendering in the render tab? For Cycles *Device* should be set to *GPU Compute*.

Comment: Can you provide any other information? What do you mean by 'only uses about 5% of it'? Is that just an offhand description, or are you measuring that somehow (and if so, how?). "it uses 5% of it" implies it is using the GPU at least a bit? Are you on Windows? Any details of the animation you can provide, eg is it a very heavy scene?

Comment: What CPU do you use, and how complex is your scene?

Comment: When i watch it up on the task manager it says that the GPU is used 5%.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows and the the animation has only one light and a house but the House has about 100 parts.I am using a ryzen 7 1700x.